# Copied site to different domain - modules not recognized - resolved

Tags: migration, modules, domain

I reviewed tutorial on migrating to a new domain.  It suggests fresh install of wordpress, then civicrm, which I did.  I changed settings in wp-includes/update/civicrm/civicrm.setting.php file to reflect new domain.  I then "dropped" all civi tables from database (at new domain, except civi_domain, and then used phpmyadmin to export large db file (just civi tables & data) from command line with "foreign key check disabled".  Then, due to .sql file, I ftp'd to user account.  Then, used the following mysql command to import db.sql.  This is culmination of 8 days of various processes and trial/fails.

mysql -u db_user_name -p db_name < db_file_to_import.sql  (it will prompt for mysql db password)

New domain worked, but the modules from "old domain" were listed and displayed as Enabled (Missing).  I am given the option to "Disable".  This is because the extensions were detailed in the db_table civicrm_extension, but no files due to fresh install.

I then ftp'd the extensions from old site to the new domain into;
/wp-content/upload/civicrm/ext/
And... then hit refresh in the extension mgr ui in civicrm and all were recognized...

I can also individually, disable, uninstall, find new, install each module and that process worked too.

In searching around for the extension info I did find one additional absolute path location from old site at /wp-content/upload/civicrm/persist/crm-ckeditor-default.js (FYI)

RESOLVED... Hope it helps someone else

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience.  The SE format is based on Questions and Answers, so ideally you would put this as a Question about missing extensions and then add an Answer about copying across the extension files.  You can add an Answer to your own Question.

Comment: Also, if you can help improve the documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/ to make it easier for others please suggest changes.  There is a pencil icon at the top to make edits.